# How to write a literal constant like "size_t s = 16 MByte"?

Tags: c++

Today in our code base found the following line and liked its elegance for writing a memory size.  Was wondering for few minutes about how this was compiling.

```
size_t poolSize = 16 MByte;
```

One solution is given as my own answer. Any other solutions?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal

Answer (score 94, accepted):

In modern C++ you should [define a literal notation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal), e.g.

```
auto operator""_MB( unsigned long long const x )
    -> long
{ return 1024L*1024L*x; }
```

Then write

```
long const poolSize = 16_MB;
```

Don't use macros, they're **Evil™**. In so many ways.

---

Disclaimer: code not touched by compiler's hands.

Comment: MiB would be more accurate

Comment: @TemplateRex: I used to argue that some 15+ years ago. But those unit designations never caught on. We're caught in frozen history, as with much else.

Comment: It seems like MiB / GiB / TiB do sometimes still get used in disk and file size / usage.  Probably it's more relevant there because non-power-of-two sizes are common, and because 1.024^n gets farther and farther away from 1 with larger prefixes.

Comment: They won't catch on unless we keep insisting on their use.

Comment: This lets you write `16_MByte` but not `16 MByte`, I think. Which is not a problem, but is worth pointing out.

Comment: Defining *M* as something different from million is far more evil than any macro.

Comment: Why do you take `unsigned long long`, but return a value that is over a _million_ times larger as just a `long`? Surely return `unsigned long long` at least?

Comment: For yet more binary/decimal fun, consider a telco E1 "2 Mbps" leased line.  These actually run at 2048000 bps.  That's not 2*10^6, nor 2^21, but 2^11 * 10^3.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The `unsigned long long` formal argument is forced by the rules of C++. See the linked to documentation over at cpprefence.com.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I know, but the return type is up to you.

Comment: @TemplateRex No-one says "mebibyte". It sounds stupid.

Comment: At the time I wrote this answer I only thought about illustrating the basic concept & syntax, with no extraneous issues. But from the comments it looks like some people at least would like some more production-like code, instead or in addition. For that, I'd use `constexpr` to support compile time constants, and I'd use a conditional expression with range checking and possible throwing to make sure the range of the return type isn't exceeded. However, that only kicks in at compile time when the `constexpr` nature is forced by being used as such. I don't know how to make this perfect.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf (Re: MiB) Git correctly uses KiB etc.

Comment: returning `long` can be dangerous... on many 32bit platforms `long` is the same size as `int`, and 1 GiB barely fits into 32bit ... even the calculation in the body could wrap already

Answer (score 14):

Of course you should use template metaprogramming for this problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<long long N, long long M>
struct is_power_of
{ 
    static constexpr bool value = (N%M != 0)? false : is_power_of<N/M, M>::value;
};

template<long long M>
struct is_power_of<0, M> : public std::false_type { };
template<long long M>
struct is_power_of<1, M> : public std::true_type { };

template<long long N, typename = typename std::enable_if<is_power_of<N, 1024>::value>::type>
struct bytes
{
    enum {value = N, next = value * 1024};   
    template<long long M>
    struct compile_time_get
    {
        enum {value = N*M};
    };
    static long long run_time_get(long long x) {return N*x;}
};

typedef bytes<1> byte;
typedef bytes<byte::next> kilo_byte;
typedef bytes<kilo_byte::next> mega_byte;
typedef bytes<mega_byte::next> giga_byte;
typedef bytes<giga_byte::next> tera_byte;
typedef bytes<tera_byte::next> peta_byte;
typedef bytes<peta_byte::next> eksa_byte;

int main()
{
    std::cout << kilo_byte::compile_time_get<3>::value << std::endl;
    int input = 5;
    std::cout << mega_byte::run_time_get(input) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
3072
5242880
```

[LIVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4874e9e4d14ef23)

Comment: I really hope this is a joke.

Comment: @akaltar: look up `std::ratio`/`std::chrono`.

Comment: I love this joke ;-)

Answer (score 6):

If you are going to be doing it a lot, then a user defined literal is the way to go.  OTOH, for one-offs (and to support older compilers and other languages), I'd go with the direct:

```
size_t poolSize = 16ul*1024*1024;
```

Answer (score 4):

It was a simple and clever use of the good old macros.

```
#define KByte *1024
#define MByte *1024*1024
#define GByte *1024*1024*1024
```

So `size_t poolSize = 16 MByte;` gets translated into

```
size_t poolSize = 16 *1024*1024;
```

Comment: It was a simple and terrible abuse of macros. Never do this.

Comment: Don't use the preprocessor for this. Since you're programming in C++, you should really use [user-defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal).

Comment: yeah, quite not c++. But I guess it was cute when the code was written 10/15 years ago

Comment: It would have been better 10 - 15 years ago to use something like `16 * MBYTE`,  and preferably defined a MBYTE as a static constant if it didn't need to be used in constant expressions.  One problem with your macro is that `var / 1 MByte` doesn't divide `var` by a megabyte like it seems, it multiplies it by a megabyte instead.

Comment: If you have to keep using macros, at the very least, this should _really_ be something like `#define KByte(x) ((x) * 1024)`, `#define MByte(x) ((x) * 1024 * 1024)`, and `#define GByte(x) ((x) * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)`, so it's less likely to break something.  Sure, that means a bit of refactoring, but it's better than any of the insanity that can happen if you misuse the current macros.

Comment: Yeah there's really nothing "clever" about this!

Comment: 100ull MByte / 16 MByte gives 6871947673600, without the ull it would just overflow. Use with caution.

Answer (score 1):

All the examples I saw were more like

```
#define KB 1024
#define MB (1024*1024)

size_t poolSize = 16*MB;
```

No magic, no questions, just works.

Comment: These are just numbers, so why would you use macros instead of `const`?

Comment: Because I can write these in header and then include that header in multiple files without worrying about how linker would handle the storage and other complex stuff. Text substitution is easy to understand.

Comment: There should really be parentheses around `1024*1024`, otherwise you'll get weird behavior if and when somebody does `double rate = 1.0 / MB`. The rule of thumb with `#define` is, if in doubt, *always* add extra parentheses.

Comment: Correct. Fixed.

Comment: @aragaer: Text substitution is actually a lot _harder_ to rationalise about, and particularly to debug. A simple `static constexpr const unsigned int KB = 1024` in a header will do.

Comment: Well, since it is `C++`, that would be correct. Unfortunately most my experience is with `C`. Which explains why `define` is what I usually saw in the code.